# Dataflow streaming job not scaleing past 1 worker

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My streaming dataflow job(`2017-09-08_03_55_43-9675407418829265662`) using `Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.1.0` will not scale past 1 Worker even with a growing pubsub queue (now 100k Undelivered messages) – do you have any ideas why?

Its currently running with `autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED` and `maxNumWorkers=10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow Engineer here. I looked up the job in our backend and I can see that it is not scaling up because CPU utilization is low, meaning something else is limiting the performance of the pipeline, such as external throttling. Upscaling rarely helps in these cases.

I see that some bundles are taking up to hours to process. I recommend investigating your pipeline logic and see if there are other parts that can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks! One of the steps in the pipeline is a a HTTP request to another service that does some heavy processing. This service is auto scaled and could handle a higher load than the current one, however the dataflow seams capped. By turning the dataflow step into a async http call, would it be able to send more parallel requests?

Comment: What is the scale of parallelism you are looking for? With the current set up, you are already getting a parallelism of about 4 * max_num_workers. It is possible for a DoFn to issue async calls, but simpler and more flexible way would be to add a 'reshuffle'[1] step. This lets you control max parallel request to your service quite easily (e.g. if you use random.nextInt(100) for shuffle key, the pipeline would have up to 100 parallel requests). 
[1]: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.html

Comment: You linked to something that is deprecated – should I reimplement it with my own GroupBy/FlatMap implementation?

Comment: The `Reshuffle` transform is marked deprecated because it is a Dataflow-specific hint rather than a Beam model concept. You could re-implement the same logic on your own, but Dataflow internally uses the `ReshuffleTrigger` for additional optimization. It's possible the `Reshuffle` transform might change or be removed in the future, but not without being replaced with a similar mechanism.

Comment: @Brodin, Please go ahead and use Reshuffle. Though it is marked deprecated, it is the recommended way to shuffle messages in Dataflow. If and when it is removed, there will be a simple replacement for it.

Comment: You can implement it with GBK. Need to ensure the messages are flushed out without getting buffered with the appropriate trigger. E.g. I used 'Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)' in my PR ( https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3612/files#diff-2fa38a7f8d24217f1f7bde0f5c7dbb40R1859 )

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class ReshuffleWithRandomKey<T>
        extends PTransform<PCollection<T>, PCollection<T>> {

    private final int size;

    public ReshuffleWithRandomKey(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<T> expand(PCollection<T> input) {
        return input
                .apply("Random key", ParDo.of(new AssignRandomKeyFn<T>(size)))
                .apply("Reshuffle", Reshuffle.<Integer, T>of())
                .apply("Values", Values.<T>create());
    }

    private static class AssignRandomKeyFn<T> extends DoFn<T, KV<Integer, T>> {

        private final int size;

        AssignRandomKeyFn(int size) {
            this.size = size;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void process(ProcessContext c) {
            c.output(KV.of(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size), c.element()));
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think @raghu-angadi and @scott-wegner?

Comment: Looks good to me. Minor stuff : You can use MapElement.via() to reduce code a bit. Renaming 'size' to something 'shards' might convey the intent better.

Comment: Did you apply `ReshuffleWithRandomKey` immediately before a ParDo with a blocking network call? Or did you embed the ParDo between `Reshuffle` and `Values`? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem, but don't follow how this increases parallelism.