# Scaling of ParDo transforms having blocking network calls

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a ParDo transform inside which I am making a blocking web service call to fetch some data. The call takes a while to return (say about 1 minute). I observed that this ParDo transform does not scale much (I am using autoscale mode) even if called on a fairly large PCollection. Perhaps this is because scaling happens only when there is heavy CPU/memory utilization and in my case, CPU/memory consumption could be low as most time is spent on waiting for the network call to return. The end result is that since scaling does not happen, only a small number of http requests are issued in parallel, and the job takes longer to finish. Any ideas/suggestions on how I can improve the situation ?

Thank You

Note:I am using Google Dataflow through Java SDK 1.9.1, and am open to moving to Apache Beam Java SDK

Comment: Do you use Java or Python?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that in my post. I use Java SDK 1.9.1 and am open to moving to Apache Beam SDK

Comment: Can you explain in some more detail to make these long network calls in your ParDo?

Comment: Using ```Reshuffle()``` before your API-calling ParDo might help.

Comment: Please include a Dataflow job ID to help debug this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the job id now . I shall try to trigger the job again, and check. But basically it boils down to this : I have several web requests (ie REST calls) to make. Each ParDo will make one web request. I thought that since there are a large number of web requests to make, it will scale. Is it expected to scale ? It did not scale for me (perhaps I am doing something wrong) . Scaling will happen only when CPU utilization or memory utilization will hit a saturation point. This may not happen with REST API calls. Is that reasoning correct ?

Comment: Subsequently we used IntraBundleParallelization and then it scaled well . Perhaps spawning multiple threads increased the load to an extent where it began to scale ?

Comment: I am not sure how to use Reshuffle() . I`m not able to understand the concept behind reshuffle . Could you please provide an example, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed currently Dataflow limits autoscaling in case the workers are not utilizing CPU enough.

This is mainly done to avoid a situation where you are doing blocking network calls in your pipeline, and as we scale up, more calls are being made and the external service gets overloaded and becomes slower, and as a result Dataflow thinks that the total amount of work to be done is even larger, and scales further up, spiraling into a positive feedback loop. The current behavior also is not optimal for this case, but it at least does not have this catastrophic failure mode.

We are considering different ways to achieve the best of both worlds, but for now this is a known issue and to work around it you'll need to either specify the number of workers explicitly (thus disabling autoscaling), or perhaps add some code that burns CPU (which is, granted, very ugly).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a streaming job, standard practice to increase parallelism for your blocking ParDo is to add a `Reshuffle` before it. See [Dataflow streaming job not scaleing past 1 worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116443/dataflow-streaming-job-not-scaleing-past-1-worker) 
In most cases, increasing number of workers does not increase parallelism/throughput greatly in a streaming pipeline.

Comment: I should qualify that the last statement about throughput is meant for blocking ParDos, not in general.