# Apache beam/KafkaIO throughput issues in Dataflow

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam (Dataflow) to process messages which are stored in Kafka. Kafka consists of 3 brokers. Each **topic** contains **only 1 partition**. (That means that 1 topic can have only 1 consumer in one consumer group) We’re using Kafka.IO to read from Kafka. (Currently we can’t repartition our topics)

I'm having throughput issues when one of the topics has a huge backlog. 
I've made various tests, to summarize, I get 1/3 of throughput in Apache Beam pipeline compare to standalone Kafka client. Even when the Dataflow scales up to X machines.

It looks that after message is read from Kafka it is processed on the same machine **always** and slow pipeline has a general impact on throughput. Am I right?

I've tried to use: `.apply("Materialize input", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())` after reading from KafkaIO. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116443/dataflow-streaming-job-not-scaleing-past-1-worker/46124129#46124129). Then the machine scaling has an impact, but CPU utilization goes crazy I need to use much more powerful machines.

Any other ideas how to improve throughput?

My KafkaIO configuration:

```java
PCollection<KafkaRecord<String, String>> readLines = p
        .apply("Read from Kafka",
               KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                       .withBootstrapServers("10.150.0.17:9092")
                       .withTopics(topics)
                       .withKeyDeserializer(KeyDeserializer.class)
                       .withValueDeserializer(ValueDeserializer.class)
                       .updateConsumerProperties(
                               new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                                       .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
                                            "earliest")
                                       .put(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, 524288)
                                       .put(ConsumerConfig.SEND_BUFFER_CONFIG, 524288)
                                       .put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-consumer-group")
                                       .put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false)
                                       .put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
                                            "http://10.150.0.17:8081")
                                       .put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false)
                                       .build()
                       )
                       .commitOffsetsInFinalize());
```

Comment: Thanks for a filing a jira for this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8121.
I have commented there in a comment. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8121?focusedCommentId=16921555&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16921555
As mentioned there, it is likely a bottleneck in your sink. Metrics & stacktraces can confirm that.

Comment: Can you add an answer for the question? That way others will know what happened.

Comment: I have a similar problem and I've tried the same workarounds but I can't get much more than 5k msgs/s despite having a pass through function after the kafka source fn. I'm not sure if this is an issue with Dataflow but it makes beam less appealing because we're only using it because we want to use Dataflow.